# Implement interface just in place in c++

Tags: c++, virtual, declaration

I want to achieve such an outcome using c++:

Java:

```
public interface ITemp {
    void onCall(double value);
}
```

In main:

```
double d=2;
ITemp mVariable = new ITemp() {
@Override
    public void onCall(double value) {
    ... what to do... you can use 'd' variable...
    }
};
```

In C++:

```
class ITemp {
public:
    virtual void onCall(double something) =0;
    virtual ~ITemp();
};
```

In main:

```
double d=2;
ITemp mVariable = .... // I cannot instantiate class containing pure virtual method
// But I want to use variable d to create a method
```

Comment: I would say "cannot be done", pointing to how Java and C++ aren't 1:1 similar in what they do and how they do it. But then again even after over 10 years C++ still surprises me sometimes, so I'll wait on the gurus to explain how it *can* be done. ;-)

Comment: Maybe you should consider using polymorphism instead. Something like IBase &x = Derived();

Comment: Can you clarify what you actually want here. Do you want different instances of `Itemp` to do different things in `onCall()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do exactly that since you can't create anonymous classes in C++, but you can do something similar:

```
int main()
{
    double d = 2;
    class T : public ITemp
    {
        double& m_v;
    public:
        T(double& v) : m_v(v) {}
        void onCall(double value)
        {
            // Do something with m_v;
            m_v *= value;
        }
    } t(d);
    t.onCall(4);
    std::cout << "d: " << d << std::endl;  // d is 8.
}
```

The reference ('&') makes `m_v` *the same variable* as `d`, but under a different name.

Comment: You _can_ have unnamed classes in C++ (but they cannot have user defined constructors).

Comment: +1 - This is the closest to closures you can get without something like C++0x.

Comment: @Mankarse: Oh yeah, forgot about that. I can't think of a way to have one with a base class, though. Not before coffee.

Comment: it's still not so pretty, when you have to call more variables than just one, in my case, I need to call functions, variables, class members etc. Making inner class I suppose isn't different from making outer class in this case. But if it's the only possibility, I have to deal with it anyway ;]

Answer (score 1):

What about constructing class with d in constructor?

```
    class ITemp {
      double m_d;
    public:
      ITemp(double d) : m_d(d) {}
      virtual void onCall(double something) = 0; // inside, you can use m_d variable         along with something for whatever you want.
      virtual ~ITemp();
    };
```

I think i do not understand what is done in onCall method and how you want to use it. If you want to work with d, pass it to constructor or pass it to onCall as another parameter.

Of course, if that is not what you are trying to do, templates would help you. They are usually used to send different types into class each time however. It seems you do not need that.

Comment: The Java code constructs an inner class that has access to a variable in the containing method (possibly even to modify it). This doesn't do the trick.

Comment: If you pass the reference instead of value itself, it will. But in that case i would make inner classes friends and pass reference to object instead of members itself.

Comment: I was trying to omit making friend classes. That was my first thought, but making constructor with a lot of variables and some functions isn't the nettiest things I expected :)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the interface as an unnamed class, but you cannot access local variables and create a closure.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    class : public ITemp
    {
    public:
        virtual void onCall(double something)
        {
            std::cout << something;
        }
    } temp;

    ITemp& itemp = temp;

    itemp.onCall(100.3145);

    return 0;
}
```